# Efficient way to sort dates with their values in a JSON Array in Kotlin

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, android-date

In Android application development using Kotlin, which would be the efficient way to sort a JSON array which got objects having dates as property values.

I want to sort my response with date and pick the latest created item. For example, my list response is

```
[
    {
        name : "Joseph"
        enrolled_at : "2019-12-17 14:16:51"
    },
    {
        name : "Infant"
        enrolled_at : "2019-12-20 10:06:22"
    },
    {
        name : "Raj"
        enrolled_at : "2020-02-10 07:19:16"
    }
]
```

I want to sort this with "enrolled_at" property date to get the recent enrolled item. The original response is huge and so I cannot get the real response here.

What would be the efficient way to sort the dates using Kotlin. Tried with [sortedWith](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) and other collections in Kotlin. Looking for suggestions.

Comment: so, what's wrong with collections sorting methods?

Comment: You need to convert string date into an actual date and then use sortedWith or sortedBy

Comment: did you try sortyBy ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to create the method that converts that String into a Date in order for your array to be sortable.

And assuming you're converting that JSON to a list of users of type:

```
data class User(val name: String, val enrolled_at: String)
```

Using the ability to create extensions in Kotlin, you can create the following String method extension:

```
fun String.toDate(): Date{
   return SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).parse(this)
}
```

Then you can sort the user's list by ascending date by doing:

```
users.sortedBy { it.enrolled_at.toDate() }
```

Comment: Consider not using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Consider java.time, the modern Java date and time API. If for API levels under 26, then either through [desuraing](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or through the backport, [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).